# Getting an error calling watson conversation service - Unauthorized : Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a node red application deployed in IBM bluemix that calls Watson Conversation Service using conversation node of node red. We use the free pricing plan for the conversation service. This has been working fine for 2-3 months but ran into an intermittent error "Unauthorized : Access is denied due to invalid credentials" today between 13:30 - 15:30 IST. We couldn't recreate the issue after 15:30 IST though. Error was thrown on purely random basis time to time. We could not find any patterns. After 5 - 10 successful calls, we got this error but it is not consistent. Is there anything wrong with conversation service today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chandana, if you are still experiencing issues, please post at [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/) and/or [open a Bluemix support ticket](https://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport). Stack Overflow is for technical programming questions. Here's a link to the kinds of questions to ask on Stack Overflow: stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic .

Comment: thanks for the links. I have raised the question to Watson slack community and they agreed that there was an issue in conversation service to which they have applied a fix. Sorry for posting support issue in programming forum.